# Date Formatter in swift

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

i want to get this type of formate -> April 20, 2018 at 9:02:00 PM UTC+5:30
for firestore timestamp. i already try this code but do not get proper formate as above.

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z"
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "IST") as TimeZone?

let result = formatter.string(from: date)
print(result)
```

already use this formatter formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d yyyy'T'hh:mm:ss a Z"

Thanks

Comment: "already try this code but do not get proper formate as above." What did it give you? For instance, I don't see a `'at'` in your format.

Comment: Need to add "at" in between are you sure.?

Comment: yes @AbhirajsinhThakore

Comment: @Rock One suggestion, save `timeStamp` in unix format like this`1524476327` and parse it at client side for UI purpose.

Comment: Don't know why new question for each `dateFormat` there are many formats so whenever requirement change you will ask a new question. Why not just google for that particular format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a 'UTC'Z" //If you dont want static "UTC" you can go for ZZZZ instead of 'UTC'Z.
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "IST")
    let result1 = formatter.string(from: date)
    print(result1)
```

> **Note:** If you do not want the **UTC** to be static in the string, you can  also use the format `"MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a ZZZZ"`

**Thank you [Larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme) For the format improvement**

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: its possible to UTC+5:30 instead of +0530 ?

Comment: Please check the Edited answer

Comment: `formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss a Z"` does the same job without needing to combine.

Comment: `HH` instead of `hh` is strange with a AM/PM afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @Larme for the suggestion,

Comment: @Rock - but it returns the GMT not UTC

Comment: Edited the answer once again for you, Now a static  'UTC' is passed so that it will return that only,

Answer (score 4):

do like

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    //If you want it in your specific format you can simply add 'UTC'
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a 'UTC'Z"
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "IST") as TimeZone?
    let result = formatter.string(from: Date())
    print(result)
```

> Note: if you want to set the currentTimezone for your string then  use the format **"MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a ZZZZ"**

you get the output as

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you don't want leading zero in hour, when hour has single digit. Also you don't need to typecast NSTimeZone into TimeZone. You can directly use TimeZone.

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' h:mm:ss a 'UTC'Z"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "IST")
let result = formatter.string(from: date)
print(result)
```

> April 23, 2018 at 3:09:01 PM UTC+0530

[image]